# Can Selenium run directly (without adb) on Android devices?

Tags: android, selenium, android-ndk, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a web test automation app for Android, and wondering if there is a way to run chromedriver (Selenium) directly on the Android device (or bundle it with my app). I realize the normal way is to run chromedriver on a PC and connect to Android devices with adb. But I would prefer my users not have to install the Android SDK, and be able to run tests on native devices even when no PC is available.

Does anyone know a way to do this? If not - would it be possible to implement the WebDriver protocol in an Android app? Are there any open-source projects that have already attempted to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#), an open source tool that implements the WebDriver protocol, to automate Android (and iOS) web testing.

I'm not sure if that answers your question specifically about running "chromedriver (Selenium) directly on the Android device", but that is how I've automated mobile testing in the past.

Comment: My understanding - please correct me if I'm wrong - is that Appium has to run from a PC with the Android SDK installed. My objective is to automate Chrome on devices _that aren't connected to a PC_, by using a native app (which, if necessary, I am willing to write myself).

Comment: Ah, I see what you are asking now, and you are correct.  Appium does not solve that particular problem as it requires a connection to the PC.  Sorry, I'm not sure how or if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To run web tests on mobile device you need to use Appium as a server.

1) Install [Appium](http://appium.io/) and start the appium server

2) Connect your mobile device with `developer options` activated and `USB debugging` enabled.

3) Create instance of `RemoteWebDriver` with appropriate capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "MyDevice");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", capabilities);
```

Use this instance of driver same way as you did with ChromeDriver.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but - as I commented below J. Paul's answer - I believe Appium has to run from a PC with the Android SDK installed, yes? 

My objective is to automate Chrome on devices that _aren't connected to a PC_, by using a native app (which, if necessary, I am willing to write myself).

Comment: Ok, I see. So then you need to find a way of running ChromeDriver executable on Android device and send commands from your test apk (basically execute Java code). I think its doable, but not sure it is an easy thing to do. You can take a look chromedriver documentation to understand how to play with service via java code: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

##### In Theory: Yes

But I think you'd need a custom driver and probably a Rooted Android phone.

The adb commands would be possible to execute in a android shell. (start chrome using flags and debugging enabled on a specific port)

For the driver, is see 3 possible solutions:

- A application which can communicate with your localhost port and connect to chrome debugging port (probably needs own developement)
- using [Termux](https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/nethunter-rootless/) or [NetHunter](https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/), a Linux environment for Android, in which you could also execute a Java or Python  driver)
- using On-Screen actions automation (seee https://github.com/Nain57/Smart-AutoClicker)

In any case, I don't think it's possible out of the box.