# Is it possible to run Selenium on Android as a standalone device (not connected via adb etc) or an alternative way

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver

There was a very similar question posted 5 years ago regarding something very similar so part of this question is asking whether things have changed.  Background: I have a python program on my PC that uses Selenium to download data from a website every day. I would like to port it to my android phone. When looking at Selenium and Appium examples that people have posted, it seems that they are always using the Emulator or connected to the real device via ADB. So the very general question is: Can Selenium be run on an Android device without being rooted and without being connected to a PC?

The older reference from 2017 is here:
[Can Selenium run directly (without adb) on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241725/can-selenium-run-directly-without-adb-on-android-devices)

If it is still the case, can you please recommend an alternative to Selenium so that programmatically, one can insert text and click on buttons in a Web Browser on Android as to emulate a user. This would run as a job scheduled on the Android phone.